# Prove that the initial-value problem $x'=f(x)$ with $x(0)=0$ has solution for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to prove the following assertion:

> Let $f$ be a continuous function of one variable, defined on all
>   $\mathbb{R}$. Let $M(r)$ denote the maximum of $|f(x)|$ for $|x| \leq
> r$. If $M(r)=o(r)$ as $r \rightarrow \infty$ then the initial-value
>   problem $$  x'=f(x) \ \ , \ \ x(0)=0 $$ has a solution on all of $\mathbb{R}$

In order to solve the problem I think this theorem could be useful, but I don't know exactly how to use it:

> If $f$ is continuous in a rectangle $R$ centered at $(t_0, x_0)$, say
>   $$
> R=\lbrace (t,x) : |t-t_0| \leq \alpha, \ |x-x_0| \leq \beta \rbrace
> $$
>   then the initial-value problem
>   $$
> x'=f(t,x) \ \ , \ \ x(t_0)=x_0
> $$
>   has a solution $x(t)$ for $|t-t_0| \leq \min \lbrace \alpha, \beta/M \rbrace$ where $M$ is the maximum of $|f(t,x)|$ in $R$.

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just write out what the theorem will allow you to conclude. Fix your rectangle with $|x-0|\leq r$. Then $f$ has maximum $M(r)$ on this rectangle. Since $f(x)$ is continuous it will stay finite on any closed set. In addition to this $M(r)=o(r)$, which means that $\frac{M(r)}{r}\rightarrow 0$. Your theorem says the solution exists for:

$|t-0|\leq \min(\infty,\frac{r}{M(r)})$,

now take $r\rightarrow\infty$. Also include the special case of $M(r)=0$.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I was a bit confused for the fact that $f$ has only one variable.

Comment: @Alex R sir can i say that solution will be unique on $\Bbb R$? As Picard theorem gives unique solution and $h=\infty$?

Comment: @neelkanth: Picard's theorem needs $f$ to be Lipchitz in $x$. To wit, take $f(x):=\sqrt{|x|}$, so for $x\geq 0$,  $x' = \sqrt{x}$.  Then $f(r)=o(r)$ for $r$ going to infinity, yet there are two solutions $x(t)=0$ and $x(t)=t^2/4$

Comment: @AlexR. thank you ...